# irreducibility in $F_2[X]/X^5+X^2+1$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $K=F_2[X]/(X^5+X^2+1)$ and $Q=T^2+T+1$.

I am trying to figure out whether $Q $ is irreducible in $K[X]$.
There is a hint in my exercise (show that a root of $Q$ verifies $X^3=1$)

What I did:

I showed that indeed, a root T of Q verifies $T^3=1$:

Let T be a root of Q. We have $T^2+T+1=0$ so $T^3+T^2+T=0$.

Substracting the first equation from the second gives $T^3=1$.

Now, I don't know how to use that to prove that Q is reducible (what I suspect) in $K[T]$

Many thanks for any help or hint.

Comment: There is a problem in the notation used in the question: $X$ is used both as an element of $K$ satisfying $X^5 = X^2 +1$, and as a formal variable for the polynomial ring over $K$. It might be better to write $Q = T^2+T+1$ in a different variable $T$.

Comment: @MarcPaul I thought there was only one element $\alpha \in K$ verifying $\alpha^5+\alpha^2+1=0$ that we add to $\mathbb{F}_2$ as an extension. If this is the case , why in the deleted answer we consider $X^5+X^2+1=0$ for the variable X? is This what leads to this confusion in notation ? Thank you!

Comment: You fixed $Q = X^2 + X + 1$ to $T^2 + T + 1$, but then you should also make the corresponding changes to "(ir)reducible in $K[T]$" and "$T^3=1$".

Comment: Now you changed too much to $T$: you also replaced $r$ by $T$. But that part was correct: you take a root $r \in K$ of $Q$ and show it satisfies $r^3 = 1$. You never get $T^3 = 1$ because $T$ is the variable of the polynomial ring $K[T]$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Hint*: Since $X^2 + X + 1$ has degree $2$, it is reducible over $K$ iff it has a root $r$ in $K$. As you showed, then $r^3 = 1$, so $r$ has order $3$ in the group of units $K^\times$. But what is the order of $K^\times$? What does Lagrange's Theorem say?

Comment: Sorry I am very new to fields extendions and just to be sure I understand, the polynomials  in $F_2[X]/X^2+X+1$ are : $\{0,1, X, X+1 \}$ ?
If that is the case then $X^2+X+1$ is irreducible because I cannot find a product of 2 elements giving $X^2+X+1$

Comment: @PerelMan I think you're getting confused by using $X$ to mean two different things, as pointed out by MarcPaul. Let $\alpha$ the coset $T + (T^2 + T + 1)$ in $L = \mathbb{F}_2(\alpha) = \mathbb{F}_2[T]/(T^2+T+1)$.  Then $X^2 + X + 1 = (X - \alpha)(X - \alpha^2)$. However, we are not considering $X^2 + X + 1$ over $L$, but over $K$. In any case, let me edit to try to simplify my answer.

Comment: Now I understand. Q is irreducible since $K^*$ has no element of order 3. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To avoid confusion, I'll write $\alpha$ for the residue class of $X$ in $K = {\mathbb F}_2[X]/(X^5 + X^2 + 1)$, so $K = {\mathbb F}_2(\alpha)$ with $\alpha^5 + \alpha^2 + 1 = 0$. Additionally, I'll look at the polynomial $Q = T^2 + T + 1$ in $K[T]$.

The question is to figure out whether or not $Q$ is reducible.

The first point to realize is that because $Q$ is of degree $2$, it is reducible if and only if it has a root in $K$.

Secondly, as the hint suggests and as the OP already figured out, every root $r \in K$ of $Q$ satisfies $r^3 = 1$. This implies that the order of $r$ in the group $K^*$ of invertible elements of $K$ is $1$ or $3$. Now $1$ cannot really happen: that corresponds to $r = 1$, but that is not a root of $Q$. However, $K^*$ is a cyclic group of $2^5 - 1 = 31$ elements and because $3 \not\mid 31$ it does not have any elements of order $3$.

Comment: $$K = {\mathbb F}_2[X]/(X^5 + X^\color{red}{2} + 1)$$

Comment: @GNUSupporter Indeed. Thanks.

Comment: I thought the ordre of $K^*$ in this case was $|K^*| = \varphi(32)=16$ with $\varphi $ is the Euler function

Comment: No, that's the order of ${\mathbb Z}_{32}^*$. $K$ is a field, so everything except $0$ is in $K^*$.

Comment: Many thanks for your explanation